# Google maps API custom map from image in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know it's possible to make a custom map from an image in javascript with google maps API as described here: [ImageMapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes)

Also I know it's possible to add overlays to an existing map, but can I build a map from custom tiles, like described in this article: [Create zoomable images](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html).

Comment: From what I've understand in the How it works section of the link you have provided they used [ImageMapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) in achieving what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tile overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) does exactly what I asked. I had to generate tiles and also override the tile url provider to load the images from disk instead of url.